# How to use less in a 'safe' way on files with huge lines?

Tags: less, large-files

I have a relatively large file, a minified json file which is about 4 Gigs. The file isn't huge...but a lot of programs choke on it because it's a single-lined file.

I have noticed `less` works ok on it as long as I press `ctrl-c` immediately upon opening the file, which then gives me a:

> Line numbers turned off  (press RETURN)

However, a lot of commands I'll try using will just hang the program, such as any search (`/`), going to the 'end' of the file (`G`), and several others. Is there a sort of guide or rule of thumb as to what commands can be used in `less` when working with large, single-lined files? So far the only items that work consistently are up/down (`j`,`k`, `ctrl-u`, `ctrl-d`, etc.).

Comment: `man less` gives the option `-n` to suppress line numbers. It says, « _**`-n` or `--line-numbers`** Suppresses line numbers.  The default (to use line numbers) may cause less to run more slowly in some cases, especially with a very large input file.  [...]_" »

Comment: For JSON, you could try passing the data through an indenter. The file will be bigger, but it's usually easier to work with a 10GB text file with short lines than a 4GB text file with a single line.

Comment: `G` will obviously read until the end of the file. I think `/` reads to the end of each line before trying to match it. I'm not sure what kind of rules you're looking for. If you ask less to read a large amount of data, you have to wait for it to finish...

Comment: In fact, if it is only one line, it is already *at* the end of file -- it is just completing the last line.